# Fixed DPI when UV unwrapping

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Cheers everyone! I'm planning to UV-unwrap models and create textures elsewhere (mainly Photoshop). However, I'd want to add sprites and geometric shapes that must keep a specific size in the texture and in the final piece.

Is there a way to fix a 300 DPI resolution in the UV map, using the absolute size of the 3D object for scale?

Of course i would need to build a rather small object to prevent enormous UV maps.

Thank you in advance for all the answers!